# Compile errors, cannot find symbol and constructor cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am getting 2 errors which are :

```
ControllingSpeed.java:89: constructor Thread in class Thread cannot be applied to given types
   Thread th=new Thread(r);
              ^
required: no arguments
found: Runnable
ControllingSpeed.java:90: cannot find symbol
   th.start(r);
     ^
symbol:   method start(Runnable)
location: class Thread
2 errors
```

I don't know the reason for the errors.

```
// Demo On JSlider

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.lang.Thread.*;

class ControllingSpeed extends JPanel{

...<snip>...

public void threadForSpeed(final ChangeEvent ce) {   // <----- cause of error ?
    try { 
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                changeSpeed(ce);
            }
        };
        Thread th=new Thread(r);
        th.start(r);                // <---- till here
    } catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc);
    }  
}
```

Comment: I have edited my post.Earlier i had passed `r` in the arguments of `start`

Comment: After your edition of your post, you still have the exact same compilation error you mention at first? I can't believe it!

Comment: Applied severe editing to narrow the scope of this problem down to the specific compile errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is quite likely that somewhere in your package you have create a class called `Thread` that is eclipsing the `java.lang.Thread` class. That class (your own) probably looks something like this:

```
class Thread {}
```

Try specifying the Thread class using the full qualified name like this:

```
    java.lang.Thread th = new java.lang.Thread(r);
```

Additionally, the `Thread#start()` method does not take an argument, so remove the `Runnable` "r" from the argument:

```
    th.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well one error is that the start method of the `Thread` class doesnt take a parameter. its just:

```
   th.start();
```

Comment: that was a fault..but i get the same 2 errors that has no `r` in error message.I have edited my post